# The submit button in a form doesn't work

Tags: python, html, django, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to submit a form. I did it a lot of times, normally it's really easy, but now I have a problem, I'm not sure where. I use Django and jquery mobile. 
The problem is that when I'm press the submit button, It doesn't do nothing. I want to get the request in the view and save the form. Here is the code:
new_category.html

```
<form  method='post' action='/new__categoryRequest>{% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <p><input class='btn' type='submit' value='Add'/></p>
</form>
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def nueva_categoria(request):
    print 'Envio del formulario de nueva categoria'
formulario=CategoriaForm()
return render_to_response('nueva_categoria.html',{'formulario':formulario}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def nueva_categoriaRequest(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        formulario=CategoriaForm(request.POST)
        print 'Nueva categoria 1'
        if formulario.is_valid():
            categoria_titulo= request.POST['titulo']
            categoria_descrpcion= request.POST['descripcion']
            categoria_tiempo_final=request.POST['tiempo_final']
            categoria=Categoria(titulo=categoria_titulo)
            categoria=Categoria(descripcion=categoria_descrpcion)
            categoria= Categoria(tiempo_final=categoria_tiempo_final)
            Categoria=Categoria(tipo=request.user.id)
            categoria.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')

        else:
            print 'nueva categoria 3'
            formulario=CategoriaForm()
            if formulario.is_valid():
                print 'De vuelta al home'
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
```

forms.py

```
class CategoriaForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Categoria
    exclude = ('tipo')
```

Sorry for programming in Spanish... 
The urls are ok, and the console dont says nothing about the post sent, so I think that the problem is in the submit button, but I dont know...

Comment: try adding `data-ajax=false` to submit button.

Comment: It doesn't work, sorry...

Comment: even if you add it to the `form` itself?

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is wrong, you aren't closing the action attr:

```
<form  method='post' action='/new__categoryRequest>{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<p><input class='btn' type='submit' value='Add'/></p>
```

Shoud be this:

```
<form  method='post' action='/new__categoryRequest'>{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<p><input class='btn' type='submit' value='Add'/></p>
```